# Angular route condition for url like 2010/10

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

How can i write `$routeProvide` when condition for url like `www.example.com/2010/10` ??

I have written condition like

```
.when( '/{year:[0-9]+/{month:[0-9]+', {
     templateUrl: WPAngular.partials + 'archive.html',
     controller: 'ByYear'
})
```

but its not working.

Comment: Hmm it can be the closing curly braces `'/{year:[0-9]+}/{month:[0-9]+}'` also you are using ngRoute which doesn't support regex params but `ui-router` does.

Comment: Be carefull when using regexps in routing, you can have bad surprises...

Comment: @Mistalis is right, consider creating a context to prevent conflict with other routes like `'/archives/:year/:month'`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the route provider supports regular expressions there, and if it did you have unmatched `{`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider for a description of the different things it can match.

Why not just:

```
.when( '/:year/:month', {
     templateUrl: WPAngular.partials + 'archive.html',
     controller: 'ByYear'
})
```

and then validate the numeric values elsewhere.

Comment: How can i validate and check if params are numeric or not??

Comment: You could validate them in your controller, or in a `resolve` block in the `.when`, but the best option is to do as @vjarysta suggests and switch to using ui-router.

Answer (score 1):

`$routeProvider` does not support regular expressions.

I suggest you to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for that, and it provides a lot of features that `$routeProvider` does not have.

Your conf would look like that :

```
$stateProvider
  .state( 'by-year', {
    url: '/{year:[0-9]+}/{month:[0-9]+}',
    templateUrl: WPAngular.partials + 'archive.html',
    controller: 'ByYear'
  });
```